# How to find this LCM sum function? $ \text{lcm}(m,n) +\text{lcm}(m+1,n) +\cdots+\text{lcm}(n,n)$

Tags: sequences-and-series, number-theory, summation, totient-function

**Problem:**

$$S=\text{lcm}(m,n) + \text{lcm}(m+1,n) +\ldots+ \text{lcm}(n,n)$$

There is already a [question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/761670/how-to-find-this-lcm-sum-function-textlcm1-n-textlcm2-n-cdots-t) on math.stackexchange for $[1,n]$ range . I am trying to generalise it further for $[m,n]$ range.

**My thoughts:**

- $\operatorname{lcm}(m, n) + \operatorname{lcm} (n-m, n) = \frac{ mn } { \gcd(m, n)} + \frac{ (n-m)n} { \gcd(n-m, n)} = \frac{ n\times n} { \gcd(m,n) }$.  should hold here too

We can write the required series as,
$S = \sum_{i=m}^{n} \frac{i.n}{gcd(i,n)}=n\sum_{i=m}^{n} \frac{i}{gcd(i,n)}$

$ A332049(n) = \sum_{i=1}^{n-1} \frac{i}{gcd(i,n)}$

$\implies A332049(n) + 1 = \sum_{i=1}^{m-1} \frac{i}{gcd(i,n)} +  \sum_{i=m}^{n} \frac{i}{gcd(i,n)} $

$\implies A332049(n) + 1 = \sum_{i=1}^{m-1} \frac{i}{gcd(i,n)} +  S/n $

$\implies A332049(n) + 1 - \sum_{i=1}^{m-1} \frac{i}{gcd(i,n)} =    S/n $

[A332049 above refers to this oeis series](https://oeis.org/A332049)

As evident we didn't benefit much from this substitution. As splitting additively into two didn't help, My hunch is we might need to split the series into two or more multiplicatively/recursively. And also I feel sum or difference of totients might come into play rather than mere totients for this. I am smelling possibility of principle of inclusion exclusion.

Another way I am thinking is,

for all $d$ in divisors of $n$

$S=$

$ \sum_{d|n}(n/d)[ (\varphi(n/d) - \sum_{i=1}^{m-1}|(gcd(i,n)=d)| ]$

I don't know how to evaluate the second part efficiently

**Summarise:**

Be it

$\sum_{i=1}^{m-1} \frac{i}{gcd(i,n)} $

or

$\sum_{i=1}^{m-1}|(gcd(i,n)=d)| $

whicheverso closed form you can suggest would do the job.